# Request.Form not working in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, request.form

I can't understand why is following code working in VS 2012 and not working in VS 2015:

getdata.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="getcase" name="getcase" action="submit2crm.aspx">
            <input id="Text1" type="text" name="txt" />
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

submit2crm.aspx.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class w2c_submit2crm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

            System.Text.StringBuilder displayValues = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postedValues = Request.Form;
    String nextKey;
    for (int i = 0; i < postedValues.AllKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        nextKey = postedValues.AllKeys[i];
        if (nextKey.Substring(0, 2) != "__")
        {
            displayValues.Append("<br>");
            displayValues.Append(nextKey);
            displayValues.Append(" = ");
            displayValues.Append(postedValues[i]);
        }
    }
    Label1.Text = displayValues.ToString();
}
}
```

postedValues still empty after form submission.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue by myself:
It is Friendly URL feature. To make Request.Form working I changed settings.AutoredirectMode to Off in config file RouteConfig.cs:

```
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

RouteConfig.cs located in App_Start folder.

This article help me to understand what the problem is:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/293/request-form-is-empty-when-posting-to-aspx-page